# Is there another word for five times, such as triple, quadruple?

Tags: single-word-requests

I forget what the word for 5 times is. I know it is single, double, triple, quadruple but forgot what the one for 5 is.

Answer (score 1):

quintuple

From Google

quin·tu·ple
/kwinˈt(y)o͞opəl/
Adjective
Consisting of five parts or things.
Verb
Increase or cause to increase fivefold.
Noun
A fivefold number or amount; a set of five.
Synonyms
fivefold