# What comes after quadruple?

Tags: numbers

I know:

1. Single
2. Double
3. Triple
4. Quadruple

But what comes next? Up to 10 would be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I form a word like "quadruple" for any number I want?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/how-can-i-form-a-word-like-quadruple-for-any-number-i-want) Also [When do the “-uple”s end?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/) and [Is there another word for five times, such as triple, quadruple?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111277/), which already have been closed as duplicates of that one.

Answer (score 15):

Next comes

- "quintuple"
- "sextuple"
- "septuple"
- "octuple"
- "nonuple"
- "dectuple"

Comment: See any Latin dictionary.

Comment: I wonder how much native speakers vary in how high they're willing to go. For example I'd say "octuple" but never "nonuple", that's my limit.